# How to add Devexpress GridView Command Column in the last of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

After I load data into `Dev Gridview`,  I add a `Delete Button`:

```
public void loadgrid()
{
         ....
         gv.DataBind();
         GridViewCommandColumn d = new GridViewCommandColumn();
         d.DeleteButton.Text = Delete;
        d.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
        d.Caption = " ";
        gv.Columns.Add(d);
}
```

But the `Column of Delete Button` is not in the last of gridview (it is in the left of `last`data column).

I really dont know why, I just think when I added, the `command column` is auto added in the last. Am I wrong???

help!!!

Comment: I guess you speak about the last column? Or the last row?

Comment: @Marguth the last column in the right of the Gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Set the VisibleIndex Property to the highes amount.

[Source](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q284987)